# How to ignore some files and directories using .gitgnore?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have a directory structured like this:

```
main_folder
 .git
 .gitignore
 rootfolder
  .DS_Store
  folder1
   .ipynb_checkpoints/filename-checkpoint.csv
   abc.txt
   def.json
   somedir
    more.json
  folder2
   .DS_Store
   .ipynb_checkpoints/file-filename2-checkpoint.csv
   rty.csv
   somedir
    uis.py
    .ipynb_checkpoints/filename1-checkpoint.csv
    .DS_Store
```

Being in the main_folder, I would like to commit everything, except all folders and files having the `DS_Store` or `ipynb_checkpoints` substring.

In this specific case, I would like to commit:

```
main_folder
 rootfolder
  folder1
   abc.txt
   def.json
   somedir
    more.json
  folder2
   rty.csv
   somedir
    uis.py
```

In `.gitignore`-file, I have added:

```
**/checkpoint.csv
**/.DS_Store
```

But not all checkpoint files have being ignored.
What command lines should I add into my `.gitignore` file located in `main_folder`-directory

Comment: If the files aren't specifically named `checkpoint.csv`—and `foo-bar-checkpoint.csv` isn't; it's named `foo-bar-checkpoint.csv` which is as different as  `Michel` vs `Jean-Michel`—then `**/checkpoint.csv` is wrong. Consider `**/*checkpoint.csv` instead, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

gitignore file has the functionality you need already built-in. You just need to have the name of the directory in the ignore file and git will ignore all files in that directory and all subdirectories:

```
checkpoint.csv
.DS_Store
```

If you want a file to be ignored just in the current directory, you can add "./{file}" to gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should be ignoring any file if it's in a directory called `.ipynb_checkpoints`:

```
.DS_Store
.ipynb_checkpoints
```

Please note that the files inside `.ipynb_checkpoints` folders were previously added to git then you would have to remove them explicitely before ignore will work for them.

---

BTW. You may want to grab a community `.gitignore` for python development from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Python.gitignore (it includes `.ipynb_checkpoints` :))